# Can't open installed app on android

Tags: android

I have finished my application in Android Studio but when I copy and paste app-debug.apk on my android phone it can't be opened after installation. Can anybody tell me what is wrong a what I need to do to make that app run. Btw when I was writting the code I was running it on my phone through USB cable without using AVD. Here is my AndrodiManifest:

```
<application
    android:debuggable="true"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".SplashActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.category.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.category.MAINACTIVITY"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".InfoActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: What does "can't open" mean? What happens when you try to open it? Does your logact say anthing?

Comment: So you copied the APK on the mobile phone and then? Did you at least installed it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is likely that your `<intent-filter>` elements are not correct.

Assuming `SplashActivity` is the first Activity the user should see when launching your app, your `<intent-filter>` should have an `<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>` element. Note that your `<action>` element has the name `android.intent.category.MAIN`, which doesn't exist.

Your `MainActivity`'s `<intent-filter>` also looks odd- `android.intent.category.MAINACTIVITY` doesn't exist, and you probably don't need to set the `<category>` (or an `<intent-filter>`) at all. See the documentation for [`CATEGORY_DEFAULT`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#CATEGORY_DEFAULT) and determine whether you actually need it.